# Can someone show working out for this fractional exponent problem (not homework)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Evaluate

## ${a^2b^7\over a^3b}$

Given a = ${2\over5}^4$

Given b = ${5\over8}^3$

I have tried my working out but I got 25/10 as the end answer - I'm obviously wrong and it will take me a very long time to type it all out so I am asking to see your answers so I can learn from them thanks.

Comment: $\frac{a^2b^7}{a^3b}=\frac{b^6}{a}$

Comment: @Vikram Incorrect. $\displaystyle\frac{a^2b^7}{a^3b}=\frac{b^{6}}{a}$

Comment: @Quincunx, thanx, typo, :D

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing is to simply first:
$$
\frac{a^2b^7}{a^3b}=\frac{aabbbbbbb}{aaab}=\frac{b^6}{a}
$$
then use what you know the values to be:
$$
\frac{b^6}{a}=b^6\cdot \frac{1}{a}=\left(\frac{5^3}{8}\right)^6 \frac{1}{\frac{2^4}{5}}=\left(\frac{5^3}{8}\right)^6 \cdot \frac{5}{2^4}
$$
which I leave to you to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

From the values of $a$ and $b$, we know that they are nonzero, so we can use one of the properties of exponents that says that $\displaystyle\frac{a^n}{a^m}=a^{n-m}$. Thus $$\frac{a^2b^7}{a^3b}=\frac{a^2}{a^3}\frac{b^7}{b^1}=a^{2-3}b^{7-1}=a^{-1}b^6$$ Now it is just a manner of plugging in values, and you are set.